# How to test run an UPDATE statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

How can I test an UPDATE statement for example to see if it would work, for example if it would actually update rows etc?

Is there a way to simulate it easily?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Use a [transaction](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-transactions.html) to wrap your update statement and a select query (to test the update) and then always roll it back.

Example:

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance - 100.00
    WHERE name = 'Alice';

SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE name = 'Alice';

ROLLBACK; -- << Important! Un-does your UPDATE statement above!
```

A transaction typically ends with a commit but since you're just testing and do not want the changes to be permanent you will just roll back.

Comment: Why are you making an update, you don't trust to psql ?:)

Comment: Does this TRANSACTION applies to all SQL versions?

Comment: @ДавидШико because I didn't write the statement.

Answer (score 58):

Wrap it in a [transaction](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html), test the results with a SELECT and rollback at the end.

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE ...;

SELECT ...;

ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: You could use RETURNING in the UPDATE query to skip the SELECT query.

Comment: If you decide to keep the changes, use `COMMIT` instead of `ROLLBACK`.

Answer (score 32):

Prepend your SQL `UPDATE` command with `EXPLAIN` [[ref](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html)], and it will **not** perform the actual update. E.g.:

```sql
EXPLAIN UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + 100.00 WHERE name = 'Alice';
```

It will not (always) tell you the number of rows which would be updated but rather tell you how many rows match the `WHERE` clause. In the above example those numbers are the same though.

You can refer to Paul Sasik's answer for a rollback approach.

Comment: "it will tell you how many lines will be affected by your command" - I don't think this is true; it just tells you how many rows it will scan.

Answer (score 5):

You could always build up a sample database on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/6ccc5/2) and try out your update statements there.

Full disclosure: I am the author of sqlfiddle.com

Comment: SQL Fiddle is a great learning tool, but setting up a multi-table DB there, just to test a query, it is not the best option. Kudos for the site tho!

Answer (score 1):

With Postgres you can use the UPDATE clause *RETURNING* to show which rows have been modificated.

```
-- example data
CREATE TABLE data(id int, text text);
INSERT INTO DATA VALUES(1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb'),(3,'ccc'),(4,'ddd');

-- original data
SELECT * from data;

-- dry-run update
BEGIN;

UPDATE
  data
SET
  text = 'modified'
WHERE
  id > 2
RETURNING
  id, text;

ROLLBACK;

-- data after dry-run update
SELECT * from data;
```

Comment: rollback is avoiding the commit of any changes

Answer (score 0):

Run the same check with a SELECT statement first: the rows returned by SELECT will be the rows modified by UPDATE

Comment: Not sufficient. There could be FKs, CHECK constraints, ... that a simple SELECT wouldn't hit. A SELECT would only test the WHERE clause but the UPDATE could fail even though the SELECT succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Given this simple update:

```
UPDATE Products
   SET price_including_vat = price * 1.05
 WHERE product_type = 'Food';
```

I would test it using something like this:

```
 SELECT price_including_vat AS price_including_vat__before, 
        price * 1.05 AS price_including_vat__after, 
        *
   FROM Products
 WHERE product_type = 'Food';
```

Actually, I'd proably engage brain and do analysis more like this:

```
WITH updated AS 
   (
    SELECT price_including_vat AS price_including_vat__before, 
           price * 1.05 AS price_including_vat__after, 
           *
      FROM Products
    WHERE product_type = 'Food'
   )
SELECT * 
  FROM updated
 WHERE price_including_vat__before = price_including_vat__after;
```